# Custom WebParts shows only the WebPart-Title

Tags: 2007, web-part, visual-studio, wss-3.0, custom

I've got a huge problem. I developed three custom webparts and deployed them to our testserver and that works just fine. So I decided to deploy them to the production server as well but when I add them to a WebPartPage there I only see the title of the WebParts but not the content.

I'm running wss3.0 with SharePoint 2007 on both environments and the webparts should read information from SharePoint lists and then show it via a Repeater control.

I added the assemblies of the webparts to the assembly cache and the controltemplates, features and layouts to the right folders on the server. I did also add the `<SaveControl />` Tags to the web.config and then run the following command.
`"%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\bin\stsadm.exe" -o installfeature -name <FeatureName> -force`

Does anyone has an idea what I'm making wrong so that the webparts work on the test server but not on the production server? Is there anything I could miss so the webparts just show their title?

Sorry that I'm not posting any sourcecode but I've no idea which part of the code could be wrong to cause an error like this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend to write proper logs in System logs(Event Viewer) and check what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you see the titles, the web parts are correctly deployed. If it was an installation issue you would get an exception page or a safecontrol error statement.

99% chance it has something to do with your code. Add some logging, redploy the dll and review the log files.

note: It might also be a good idea to insert a try-catch statement and return a proper error message to the end-user upon an exception.

Comment: Thanks, I found my mistake. It was a very stupid one.. The admin account doesn't have an entry in the SharePoint list with the user details so of course there is no content to show in the webpart. I feel so stupid now

Comment: No problem, as long as you learn from those mistakes. ;-)